# How do I implement timer using JLabel on JPanel?

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, timer

I would like to get a set variable of the object inst, then set it to a JLabel and set that to the current JLabel that's already on the panel. But I would like for the variable (inst.Time (which represents seconds)) of the object 'inst' to decrement  by one and remove the current JLabel and add to the panel the updated, decremented inst.Time.

I would like to decrement by 1 second as countdown timer until it reaches 0 and come out of the method WaitAndEnterIntoWorkArea. Could someone please show how to do so with the given code? Help please. Thank you

int.Time is an integer

```
 private int WaitAndEnterIntoWorkArea(Instruction inst) // 'inst' is an object of Instruction arrayList
    {
        int index = 0;
        int nFirstYDirectionToMove = 1;

        JLabel busy = new JLabel(String.valueOf(inst.Time) + "s"); //inst.Time is a time that was set for that particular 'inst' and set the busy JLabel to show time + s, e.g. 5s or 3s (s represents seconds)
        busy.setFont(font3);
        busy.setForeground(Color.RED);

         if(inst.WorkArea.startsWith("anvil")) //If inst.WorkArea is set to "anvil" Go into the block of code
        {
            nFirstYDirectionToMove = 1; //Move over one (Not important)

                                                                      //I would like to decrement inst.Time 1 at a time to 0 and add to JPanel every second 
            while(true)
            {
                synchronized("row1" + String.valueOf(index)){
                    if(row1[index].getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Open")) //If JLabel row1[index].getText() is already set as text "Open" execute the if statement;
                    {
                                                                                                                              //I would like to remove the current JLabel (row1[index]) and add the 1 second decremented JLabel to the panel
                        panel.remove(row1[index]); //Remove the JLabel of row1[indexOfArea]  (row1 is an array of JLabels) from the panel
                        row1[index] = busy; //Set JLabel text of row1[index] to the busy JLabel //Set the 1 second decremented JLabel to the current JLabel
                        panel.add(row1[index]); //Add the JLabel with the new text label with something like e.g. 5s or 4s, etc. to the panel
                        revalidate();
                        repaint();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, simply calling `busy.setText(String.valueOf(inst.Time) + "s");` should be all you need. But as always, I would highly recommend using JavaFX instead of Swing.

As for the timing try

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(()-> busy.setText(...), 0, 1000);
```

Comment: But how would I make sure it changes the JLabel decrementing by 1 one second at a time? I believe I need to do sleep(1000) but where or how should I use it?